# Understanding of deserialisation of Jackson (fasterxml)

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, lombok, fasterxml

```
How does Jackson deserialisation work when creating a Java object from JSON?
```

> A common conception is that it first calls the No Argument Constructor and
>   then proceeds to call setters.

*But*,

- What happens if there is no No Argument Constructor?
- Can Jackson be asked to
  choose some other constructor?
- Is there any issue with Boilerplate
  code generators like Lombok?

Answer (score 4):

> Simply put, Jackson first calls a constructor to instantiate an object
>   and then proceeds to call setters on remaining fields.

*Now, how does it decide which constructor to call and what are the remaining fields?*

- **If there are no special annotations defined on a constructor, Jackson will always look for No Argument Constructor**. We will come on special annotations shortly. **If the Jackson does not find a No Argument constructor, it will throw an error.**
- Since fasterxml 2.7, **Jackson also looks for [@ConstructorProperties annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/ConstructorProperties.html)**. In case of multiple constructors having this annotation, it will choose the one with maximum arguments. For the rest of the fields, it calls their setter.
- **You can also use @JsonCreator to call a specific constructor**. But @ConstructorProperties will still interfere with it. Even though @JsonCreator can be used on a single constructor, @ConstructorProperties can be used on many.
- **Lombok annotates its All Args Constructor with @ConstructorProperties annotation**. So that might interfere with default Jackson working as well.

Comment: I think it is easier to look at official documentation :-)

Comment: Welcome your comment @oleg.cherednik , Can you also drop a link to official documentation explaining this? Might be helpful to someone who is reading this.

Comment: Very helpful :)